# Создание скроллинга

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Нашел в интернете сайт [Интернет магазин](https://www.citilink.ru/). Как добиться, чтобы было как на этом сайте, а именно - левый столбец сбоку (с иконками)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не прокручивался при скроллинге, а правая часть сайта прокручивалась.

Comment: `position: fixed;`

Comment: @UModeL а `no-repeat`?

Comment: `account: no-repeat` ? Тоже можно.

Comment: @goodsoft, вы [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1250962) бы вопрос решили.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1251401/%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b3-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0 Как только разберусь с ним, отмечу ответ